# get method not working on Parse current User

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am making an express app with Parse. In my cloud code, I am trying to get an attribute of the current user, but it is returning me `undefined`. My code looks like following:

```
app.get('/home/subscriptions',function(req,res){

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = Parse.User.current();

    var ifstud = user.get("isStudent");

    console.log('student: ' + ifstud); // undefined
    console.log('id: ' + user.id); // OK. works fine.
    }
```

I am able to retrieve the `id` of the user as above but not able to call the `get` method on `user`. In their API reference, they have mentioned that `Parse.User.current()` returns a `Parse.Object`, so I think in `user` I have _User object and I should be able to call all methods supported by a `Parse.Object`.

What might be the issue here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and putting this answer for future reference to users who visit this question.

The `Parse.User.current()` returns only a pointer to the user and not the complete user object. To get access to all fields of the user, fetch the entire object using the `fetch` method.

```
var fullUser;
Parse.User.current.fetch().then(user){
fullUser = user;
}).then(function(){
// Place your code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be: `var ifstud = Parse.User.get("isStudent");`

Comment: No. This is wrong, `Parse.User` has no method `get`

Comment: So neither `Parse.Object.current( ) ` has the get method. https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_current

Comment: I don't think you are getting my point, `Parse.User.current()` returns a `Parse.Object`, which implies that it should support `get` method since every Parse Object supports it.

Comment: What if you do a `console.log(user)`?